# Antdv5 table scroll style

Tags: css, reactjs, antd

I am trying to change the style of scroll bar in antd5 table version.

I have already changed the style in v4 it was worked but after upgrading it is not working

.ant-table-body::-webkit-scrollbar{
width:4px

It is working v4 but not in v5

Any suggestions to make it work

Answer (score 0):

This should do it!

```
.ant-table-wrapper .ant-table{
  scrollbar-color: unset;
}
```

Comment: Fixed by adding scrollbar-color auto

Answer (score 0):

*antd: 5.15.0*

```css
// Try this
.ant-table-body {
  scrollbar-width: auto;
  scrollbar-color: auto;
}

// custom scrollbar
.ant-table-body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 4px;
}

.ant-table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: #e1e6e6;
}

.ant-table-body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

[image]

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jamcdq?file=index.css)